# Random Internal Server Error 500 after apache and system update

Tags: apache, internal-server-error

I'm not 100% sure that the real source of the problem is apache (could be php or other), but I'd like start from here as the only logs that provides me with information (with trace4 level) is apache log. No information appears from other logs.

I have:
- Linux 4.7.4-100.fc23.x86_64
- Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora)
- mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.26-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- PHP Version => 5.6.25

The problem: random internal server error 500. Random because, for example, if a page produces the error and do "reload" then it works. The same page may not work as well as work. Sometimes you can use the site for several minutes with no problems, then suddenly there is the error.

When error occurs, this is all that I get from the log file (with loglevel = trace4):

```html
[...]
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.151052 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 151.25.206.200:38368] 151.25.206.200 - - [www.centrometeo.com/sid#55c3e3673400][rid#7f8c8000e9d0/subreq] [perdir /home/web/centrometeo.com/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php', referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.151092 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 151.25.206.200:38368] 151.25.206.200 - - [www.centrometeo.com/sid#55c3e3673400][rid#7f8c8000e9d0/subreq] [perdir /home/web/centrometeo.com/] pass through /home/web/centrometeo.com/index.php, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913003 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(567): [client 151.25.206.200:38368] Headers from script 'php.fcgi':, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913097 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   Status: 500 Internal Server Error, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913130 2016] [core:trace1] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(649): [client 151.25.206.200:38368] Status line from script 'php.fcgi': 500 Internal Server Error, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913162 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913191 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM", referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913218 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   Content-Encoding: gzip, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913246 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   Vary: Accept-Encoding, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913275 2016] [core:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] util_script.c(568): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913395 2016] [http:trace3] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] http_filters.c(1006): [client 151.25.206.200:38368] Response sent with status 500, headers:, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913432 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] http_filters.c(835): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913458 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] http_filters.c(835): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   P3P: CP=\\"NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM\\", referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[Fri Sep 30 07:41:39.913481 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 17957:tid 140241771534080] http_filters.c(835): [client 151.25.206.200:38368]   Content-Encoding: gzip, referer: http://www.centrometeo.com/modelli-numerici/modello-wrf-nmm/559-wrf-mslp-6hprec-ita
[...]
```

Note the use of fcgi. Apache is indeed configured with event/php-fpm/FastCGI, but the same thing happens with "normal" prefork / php!
Until a few days ago it did not happen, it started after updating the system (kernel, apache, php, mariadb).
I do not really know what to do.

Thank you very much.

Additional information:

/var/log/httpd/error_log, at "crash time":
[Fri Sep 30 19:09:03.897325 2016] [mpm_event:trace4] [pid 30339:tid 139796798162688] event.c(930): socket reached timeout in lingering-close state

Comment: Those log entries do not really help. They only state the obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately the system does not return to me nothing more

Comment: But those are just debug statements from the rewriting module. There has to be a real error entry for each http500 in the servers error log. Those are not shown here. Maybe you look in the wrong log file?

Comment: /var/log/httpd/error_log, at "crash time":
[Fri Sep 30 19:09:03.897325 2016] [mpm_event:trace4] [pid 30339:tid 139796798162688] event.c(930): socket reached timeout in lingering-close state

Comment: Please always add additional information right into the question, nit into comments.

Comment: But at least that is a hint you can start a research with.

Comment: Sorry, I just did it... but i don't understand the problem.. what do you think?